# change text in one div dynamically based on text on other 2 divs

Tags: jquery

I have three divs. qty, price and cost. cost is just a multiplication of price * qty.

```
<div class="qty">1</div>
<div class="price">49</div>
<div class="cost"><div>

<div class="add">ADD</div>
```

then I have a add button which increases the qty values.

Jquery

```
$('.add').on('click',function(){
        $('.qty').text(parseInt($('.qty').text()) + 1);
});
```

now I want to put a text in "cost" div which is qty*price. And this should dynamically change with change in qty. How should this be done??

Comment: It seems pretty similar to what you're already doing.  Have you made an attempt?  Perhaps you could post that code along with how it fails.

Comment: And use the [radix with `parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the only way to change `qty` is by pressing `add` then a it is trivial to put the cost update change code there:

```
$('.add').on('click',function(){
     var qty = parseInt($('.qty').text()) + 1,
         price = parseInt($('.price').text());
     $('.qty').text(qty);
     $('.cost').text(qty * price);
});
```

If you are planning to add a `remove` button, then you should create a separate update function:

```
$('.add').on('click',function(){
    $('.qty').text(parseInt($('.qty').text()) + 1);
    update_cost();
});
$('.remove').on('click',function(){
    $('.qty').text(parseInt($('.qty').text()) - 1);
    update_cost();
});

var update_cost = function() {
    var qty = parseInt($('.qty').text()),
        price = parseInt($('.price').text());
    $('.cost').text(qty * price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.add').on('click',function(){
        $('.qty').text(parseInt($('.qty').text()) + 1);
        $('.cost').text(parseInt($('.qty').text()) * parseInt($('.price').text());
});
```